# Django query self referencing queryset

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have a model Thing that is self referencing. The relation copied_from is being used to save the Thing-Object that the current Thing-Object was copied from. Here is my Model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    copied_from = models.ForeignKey("Thing", related_name="copies", null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, ...)
    ...
```

What I would like to achieve is to get all Things from a collection that have no been copied. I was thinking about using `union`to take all Things and "substract" all things that have been copied. The issue is that in my solution I had to iterate over the Queryset where `copied_from__is_null=False` to get the ids of Things that have been used to create a copy. This is of course not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Thing.objects.filter(copied_from=None)
```

This will thus retrieve all `Thing`s where the `copied_from` is `None`.

If you want to retrieve all `Thing`s that are no copies, and have not been copied from, you can work with:

```
Thing.objects.filter(copied_from=None, copies=None)
```

or if you want to retrieve `Thing`s for which no `Thing` exists that is a copy from that, you can work with:

```
Thing.objects.filter(copies=None)
```

This works since we perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `Thing` table, and only retrieve `Thing`s fro which the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is `NULL`.